# Pandas reshaping dataframe to required number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which i need to append one below the other. Unfortunately, the two dataframes  are of different sizes:

```
df1

Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
11  65  45  76  90

df2
2   7   9   5
```

*df2 is in date format

The required output is as follows:

```
df_new

Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
11  65  45  76  90
2   7   9   5   0
```

I tried append/concat of the two dataframes:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame( np.concatenate( (df1.values, df2.values), axis=0 ) )
```

But i got the following error:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 5 and the array at index 1 has size 4

Wherever the df2 shapes are not matching the df1 shape, i want to create 0 value columns. So, I tried to reshape the dataframe to suit my requirements of increased columns but its not working:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(df2.values.reshape(1, 5))
```

but i get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (1,5)

Any way out of this?

Please note, the df1 is a variable dataframe and may increase or decrease in size at each iteration. Any way to keep it flexible instead of actually specifying the number of columns in reshape?

Comment: is df2 a series or dataframe?

Comment: both df1 and df2 are dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
df1
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
0   11  65  45  76  90
df2 = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
    0   1   2   3
0   2   7   9   5

#get df1 and df2 to have similar names
mapp = dict(enumerate(df1.columns))
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(mapp)
#using @anky's suggestion : df2.columns=df1.columns[:df2.shape[1]]

#concatenate both dfs, and fillna on the null value
pd.concat((df1,df2)).fillna(0)


   Mon  Tue Wed Thu Fri
0   11  65  45  76  90.0
0   2   7   9   5   0.0
```

Comment: nice. I'll add that